# How to listen for notifications in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to catch the notifications recived by a site in Puppeteer.
I did this method to allow notification

```
let puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
async function run(params) {
    let brz = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    let page = await brz.newPage()
    page.goto('https://web.telegram.org/z/')
    let context = brz.defaultBrowserContext()
    await context.overridePermissions("https://web.telegram.org/z/", ["geolocation", "notifications"])    
}
run()
```

But I do not know that how can I listen to notifications. how can I do it ?